# Put a stack view at the center of the screen in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview

I am new in iOS application development. In my application I need a login form at the centre of the screen. I put all the elements in a `UIStackView` and that looks fine, but this `UIStackView` not align centred in all screens. How to make this `UIStackView` at the centre of screens.

Comment: Apply AutoLayout Constraints to stackview, 2 constraints needed = 'horizontally center in container' and 'vertically center in container'

Answer (score 3):

Add the Alignment Constraints as shown in the screenshot below and it will align the stackview to the center of the screen for all devices

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `viewDidLoad()`, and `viewWillTransitionToSize()` to programmatically center the view. So Long as you have an IBOutlet bound to the stack view (called stackView in this example), this should work

```
stackView.frame.origin.x = view.frame.width/2 - stackView.frame.width/2
stackView.frame.origin.y = view.frame.height/2 - stackView.frame.width/2
```

just add this code in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillTransitionToSize()`, depending if your program allows rotation, `viewWillTransitionToSize()` is optional. If you do use `viewWillTransitionToSize()`, there should be a parameter for size that you can replace `view.frame` with.

`viewDidLoad()` is called on startup, and `viewWillTransitionToSize()` is called whenever the phone is rotated, if you want that functionality.